# Is this a Sinatra config issue, or an Apache config issue?

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra

I haven't decided if this is an Apache issue, or a Sinatra issue, basically, we have a bunch of little apps running on a single server, we deploy them with just built-in webrick instances and use apache to re-route those requests by subdomain to the right port. I am using gollum which is a sinatra app with a git persistence layer, but I am getting an unexpected app routing when it redirects (after edit action). I'm not sure if I can fix this by passing a startup option to Sinatra, or by configuring in the virtual host declaration for the app a rewrite rule. Please in your answer include which option you think is best and an example of how it might be accomplished. 
Thanks,

```
# apache virtualhost declaration
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName wiki.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3006
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3006
</VirtualHost>
```

resolves with sinatra fine for GETs, eg

```
wiki.domain.com/Home
```

but fails on sinatra redirect

```
# expected
wiki.domain.com/Home

# actual
wiki.domain.com:3006/Home
```

and here is the Sinatra action (source: https://github.com/github/gollum/blob/master/lib/gollum/frontend/app.rb )

```
post '/edit/*' do
  name   = params[:splat].first
  wiki   = Gollum::Wiki.new(settings.gollum_path)
  page   = wiki.page(name)
  format = params[:format].intern
  name   = params[:rename] if params[:rename]

  wiki.update_page(page, name, format, params[:content], commit_message)

  redirect "/#{CGI.escape(Gollum::Page.cname(name))}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a long shot, but perhaps the URLs in the ProxyPass directives need to have a trailing `/`? That’s how it is in the documentation, and I got some strange entries in error.log without them.